# Continuous solution to PDE with discontinuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

While working on a statistical physics problem I encounter the following version of heat equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\partial^2_xP(x,t) - \partial_tP(x,t) - 1_{x > 0}P(x,t) = 0.
\end{equation}
Where $1_{x>0}$ is a step function which is $1$ if $x > 0$ and $0$ otherwise. I'm interested in the solution over the domain $(x,t) \in [-1,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ with boundary conditions $P(x,0) = f(x)$ (for some function $f(x)$), and $P(-1, t) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} P(x,t) = 0$.

I suppose that any 'solution' to this PDE will not be twice differentiable at $x = 0$ due to the discontinuity, so I should think of this as $2$ separate PDEs, one for $x > 0$ and another for $x < 0$. Then the PDE itself seems to tell me nothing about the boundary condition for $x \rightarrow 0^-$ or $x \rightarrow 0^+$. Although physical intuition suggests that $P$ and $\partial_xP$ should be continuous across $x = 0$, I don't want to justify the result using intuition.

However, what if I'm interested in the solution that is consistent with the solution obtained by replacing $1_{x > 0}$ with something smoother before limiting it to $1_{x > 0}$. For instance, approximate $1_{x > 0}$ by convoluting it with a bump function $\Phi_\epsilon(x) = N(\epsilon)e^{1/(\epsilon^2-x^2)}1_{|x|<\epsilon}/\epsilon$, where $N(\epsilon)$ is a unit normalization, then obtain the solution $P_\epsilon(x,t)$ which is smooth. I suppose, my question would then be

1. Do we know that $P_\epsilon$ converges to a solution $P$ of the original PDE in some sense? (i.e. point-wise a.e., $L^1$, $L^2$, or uniformly?).
2. Do we know anything about the boundary condition of $P$ across the boundary $x=0$?